# Default SQL Server 2008 locking behaviour

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008.

- What is the default lock behaviour with `UPDATE`?

  - `NOLOCK`?
  - `ROWLOCK`?
  - `PAGLOCK`?
- How can I tell what the current level of lock is for a table?

Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on how much you're updating. Locks will escalate as the size of the query increases. If many rows within the same page will be modified, SQL Server will escalate to a `PAGLOCK`. If many pages will be modified, it will escalate to a `TABLOCK`.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, HoBT means "Heap or B-Tree": in other words, a table or an index.

Comment: Slight correction: row/key locks are never escalated to page locks. They are only escalated directly to table locks. However, the database engine may mix row and page locks for a single statement. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior for update is to first take a row-level update (U) lock to read the data, followed by an exclusive (X) lock to write it.

You can see the current lock status of all objects in your DB by running "exec sp_lock".